# when i start my 1500 dodge ram rpm goes up and down in morning

Tags: cel, dodge, rough-idle, mil, cold-start

When I start my Dodge Ram 1500 in the morning, the RPM goes up and down for about 4 times from 1000 to 2000 and it sounds like the truck is gonna shut off. It also has a check engine light on. Just bought the truck. What might be the cause of this? Thanks.

Comment: Please add more information. Year, Engine Size, Transmission Type (AT/MT + 4x4/2x4)

Comment: Does is the issue still present once the truck is at operating temperature (all warmed up)?

Answer (score 1):

Bad idle or auxiliary air valve of some sort. Cold-air valve, idle-up solenoid, EGR valve.